# Using Docker multi-stage builds

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have two containers for two separate sites and one container for nginx. All I want to do is to copy build files of each site to `/usr/share/nginx/html/<site_name>/` in nginx container. I want to keep separate `Dockerfile` for each site and have named site containers as `builder_one` and `builder_two` to copy files from these in nginx `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./conf.d/ /etc/nginx/conf.d/
RUN mkdir /usr/share/nginx/html/site_one
RUN mkdir /usr/share/nginx/html/site_two
COPY --from=builder_one /usr/src/site_one/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/site_one/
COPY --from=builder_two /usr/src/site_two/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/site_two/
```

How ever, I get an error:

```
------
 > [dockernginx-nginx] FROM docker.io/library/builder_two:latest:
------
failed to solve: failed to load cache key: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

It fails when running `COPY` command as it tries to pull the container from Docker registry. Why? How do I copy files to nginx container correctly?

---

Maybe there is another way I could achieve this?

Comment: `COPY --from` takes an _image_ name (or an alias from within the current `Dockerfile`).  How did you build the two images with the content; are they in fact named `builder_one` and `builder_two`?

Comment: @DavidMaze I used an alias name, as in `FROM node:latest AS builder_one`. Expected it to work across docker files. Referring to them by container name worked. Thanks.

Comment: That syntax only works within a single Dockerfile.  You'd have to use the `docker build -t image-name:tag` name in a different Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You clarify in comments that you have three separate Dockerfiles, and start the first two with `FROM base-image AS builder_one` syntax.  That alias syntax only works within a single Dockerfile; the aliases aren't persisted as part of the image and can't be referenced from other Dockerfiles.

`COPY --from` can also take a full image name.  For the specific setup you describe, you need to build each of the component images with a known tag

```bash
docker build -t myname/builder-one ./site_one
docker build -t myname/builder-two ./site_two
```

and then in the final Dockerfile, use those image names

```bash
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./conf.d/ /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY --from=myname/builder-one /usr/src/site_one/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/site_one/
COPY --from=myname/builder-two /usr/src/site_two/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/site_two/
```

The component images don't need `FROM ... AS` syntax, and you can generally remove an `AS alias` part of a Dockerfile's final stage's `FROM` line.

Comment: I want to run everything through a single `docker compose` configuration. Is that possible without building site images separately? I tried using `depends_on` for `nginx` service configuration where I list both sites, but that does not help and I still need to build site images separately first.

Comment: Compose has no way to say that one image build depends on another.  There are use cases like this where you can imagine wanting it; another example is trying to build a base image with common libraries and tools and then extend it in other services.  For this particular setup, a single multi-stage Dockerfile would probably give the most seamless Compose experience.

Comment: "Compose has no way to say that one image build depends on another."

But isn't that what [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#depends_on) does? Using that does build the dependency images first, and then the dependee, it's just that I cannot reference them by name in the final Dockerfile.


Anyway, I will probably go with a single Dockerfile, or even building images separately, which isn't that much of a problem.

Comment: No, `depends_on:` says that one _container_ can't start before another _container_.  You can't constrain the `build:` ordering.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the image names from your previous builds in the same docker file.

In your example:

```
FROM <builder_one_image_name> as builder_one
FROM <builder_two_image_name> as builder_two

FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./conf.d/ /etc/nginx/conf.d/
RUN mkdir /usr/share/nginx/html/site_one
RUN mkdir /usr/share/nginx/html/site_two
COPY --from=builder_one /usr/src/site_one/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/site_one/
COPY --from=builder_two /usr/src/site_two/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/site_two/
```